# If equals condition in mustache

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mustache

In my application I have a database with users. User have String field named Gender. I want to make a form, where user can edit his profile. It's should be filled with existing data.

I have such post method in java code:

```
@GetMapping("/edit/profile")
    public ModelAndView editProfile(Map<String, Object> model){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(auth.getName());

        model.put("name", user.getName());
        model.put("last_name", user.getLastName());
        model.put("company", user.getCompany());
        model.put("address", user.getAddress());
        model.put("gender", user.getGender());
        model.put("birth_date", user.getBirthDate());

        return new ModelAndView("edit_profile", model);
    }
```

And this is my mustache edit_profile template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>To do list profile editing</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Profile editing</p>

<form action="/api/users/update" method="post">
    <div><label> Name : <input type="text" name="name" value="{{name}}" /> </label></div>
    <div><label> Last Name : <input type="text" name="lastName" value="{{last_name}}" /> </label></div>
    <div><label> Gender : <br>
        {{#gender}}
            {{#"male"}}
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
            {{/"male"}}
            {{#"female"}}
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked> Female
            {{/"female"}}
        {{/gender}}
        {{^gender}}
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
        {{/gender}}
    </label></div>
    <div><label> Company : <input type="text" name="company" value="{{company}}" /> </label></div>
    <div><label> Birth Date : <input type="date" name="birthDate" value="{{birth_date}}" /> </label></div>
    <div><label> Address : <input type="text" name="address" value="{{address}}" /> </label></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}" />
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to realise logic where:

```
if(gender)
   if(gender.equals("male"))
      male radio button checked
   if(gender.equals("female"))
      female radio button checked
else
   no radio buttons checked
```

Now it doesn't work correctly, please tell me how i can make if equals conditions in mustache?

Comment: learn the basics before going into big frameworks. there is no reason to go into services if you don't know how to compare String (or any) Object's values

Comment: `if(gender == "male")` should be `if(gender.equals("male"))`. Don't use the `==` operator to compare `String`s, they are objects and the comparison will not consider the values only.

Comment: And there's no need to decompose the user object in your controller; just add the whole object to the model. Also, read about `@AuthenticationPrincipal`. Obtaining any information by means other than based on method parameters is usually a poor design. Finally, consider Thymeleaf--it's a bit simpler, _and_ you won't have to remember to include the CSRF token because it's done for you automatically.

Comment: Im sorry about == and equals issue, but my question was not about java code, it was about mustache. Anyway thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the best way to use boolean in model i guess.

java:

```
            if(!user.getGender().isEmpty()) {
                if(user.getGender().equals("male"))
                    model.put("gender", false);
                else if(user.getGender().equals("female"))
                    model.put("gender", true);
            }
```

mustache:

```
        {{#gender}}
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" > Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked> Female
        {{/gender}}
        {{^gender}}
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
        {{/gender}}
```